# Is derivative always continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Is the derivative of a differentiable function always continuous?

My intuition goes like this: If we imagine derivative as function which *describes* slopes of (special) tangent lines to points on a curve given by $f(x)$, then that slopes must be gradually bigger or smaller, but also I am not sure if this is true.

I can't find counter example; $(x^2)' = 2x, (\sin{x})'= \cos{x}, (e^x)' = e^x,$ etc. This derivatives are all continuous functions.

Examples, intuition, proofs  - all are welcome.

Comment: The graduality is described by the *mean value property* of the derivative, which is infact true! However, continuity is far too much to demand.

Comment: Study $f(x) = x^2 \sin\frac1x$ with $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not the case. It is true that there cannot be a **jump**, but there is an other possibility for discontinuities: oscillations. Take for example $f$ defined by
$$
f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)
$$
for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then $f$ is differentiable (check it!) but the derivative is not continuous at zero (check it!). In the original function, the oscillations are made insignificant by a scaling around zero, but this can change by differentiation.

Next time, you might want to check the Wikipedia entry on your subject before asking the question here.

Comment: $f$ is not defined at $0$, and hence is not differentiable/continuous at $0$...

Comment: @DonThousand I had for some reason forgotten the "=0". I have added it now.

Comment: @Mushu Nrek, sorry for late comment but I don't understand how $f$ is differentiable - slopes are going "crazy" in both directions from $x = 0$...

Comment: You have to come back to the definition of derivative. It is $\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\dfrac{x^2\sin(1/x)}{x}= x\sin(1/x)$. Since $\sin$ is bounded, this goes to zero as $x$ goes to zero. That means that $f$ is differentiable at zero with $f'(0)=0$.